# Self-intersection of a curve in a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $X$ be an affine surface over $k$. Suppose $\phi: \mathbb{A}^1 \to X$ is a non-constant morphism. Then we know that $Im(\phi)$ is closed in $X$. Is it true that $\phi$ self intersects at finitely many points i.e. there are finitely many unordered pairs $(t_0, t_1)$ such that $\phi(t_0) = \phi(t_1)$? I think it is true since there are finitely many points in $Im(\phi)$ where $\phi$ is not smooth. The singularity of $\phi$ is at those points precisely where $\phi$ intersects itself. 
Please give some hint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily --- Let for example $X = \mathbb{A}^2$ and for $x \in \mathbb{A}^1$ define
$$
\phi(x) = (x^2,0) \in \mathbb{A}^2.
$$
Then of course $\phi(x) = \phi(-x)$ for any $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer shows why things can go wrong.

Fact: given a (rational) map $\phi\colon \mathbb{A}^1$ to some $\mathbb{A}^n$, non-constant,  there exists $\alpha(t)$ a rational function $\alpha(t)$, and $\psi$ invertible (rational) map such that
$$\phi(t)= \psi( \alpha(t))$$

This follows from [Lüroth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem), if you reinterpret the algebraic statement.  A discussion of this fact is at the beginning of the Shafarevich's book on A G.   Probably this thing has appeared on the site before.

Now for $\psi$ you have the properties you want.

Comment: I want to conclude that either $Im(\phi)$ is an embedded $\mathbb{A}^1$ in $X$ or it is a curve in $X$ which is an image of $\mathbb{A}^1$ having singularity at finitely many points. The singularities are at those points where the curve self intersects.